# stop my robot if /cmd_vel doesn't receive a message within a certain time period

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can make my robot stop moving when /cmd_vel doesn't receive a message within a certain time period

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292512/stop-my-robot-if--/cmd_vel-doesn%27t-receive-a-message-within-a-certain-time-period/) by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-29**:
@abdelkrim: take a look at how (fi) `diff_drive_controller` does this: [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/d43e5a250f9ae2bb99097eb10dc6d29b0fddfc6e/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L427-L432).

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-05-29**:
@gvdhoorn  yeah exactly what i am looking for thank you ... but i still have question how i can implement that in my node i am coding with python and in this example it's not very clear how  he used timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've created a Python script that does that, using the /clock topic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Clock
import time

class Timer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd_vel_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/cmd_vel', Twist, self.sub_callback)
        self.cmd_vel_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
        self.clock_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/clock', Clock , self.sub_clock)
        self.ctrl_c = False
        self.ref_time = -1
        self.current_time = -1
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdownhook)
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    
    def init_timer(self):
        self.ref_time = self.current_time
    
    def sub_clock(self, msg):
        self.current_time = msg.clock.secs
        if self.ref_time == -1:
            self.init_timer()
        print 'Seconds without cmd_vel cmd:' + str((self.current_time - self.ref_time))
        if (self.current_time - self.ref_time) > 15:
            self.stop_robot()
            self.init_timer()
        
        print 'Ref Time:' + str(self.ref_time)
        print 'Current Time:' + str(self.current_time)
    

    def sub_callback(self, msg):
        self.init_timer()

    def publish_once_in_cmd_vel(self, cmd):
        while not self.ctrl_c:
            connections = self.cmd_vel_publisher.get_num_connections()
            if connections > 0:
                self.cmd_vel_publisher.publish(cmd)
                break
            else:
                self.rate.sleep()

    def shutdownhook(self):
        self.stop_robot()
        self.ctrl_c = True

    def stop_robot(self):
        cmd = Twist()
        cmd.linear.x = 0.0
        cmd.angular.z = 0.0
        self.publish_once_in_cmd_vel(cmd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('timer_test', anonymous=True)
    timer_object = Timer()
    rospy.spin()
```

Basically, it works like this:

- In the initialization of the class, we define 2 subscribers, for /cmd_vel and for /clock,
  and 1 publisher for /cmd_vel.
- The init_timer function just restarts the counter
- sub_clock is the subscriber for the /clock topic. It checks if a certain period of time
  has passed (15 seconds in this case). If so, it restarts the counter and stops the robot.
- sub_callback is the subscriber for the /cmd_vel topic. If a message is published into the
  topic, the counter will be restarted.
- publish_once_in_cmd_vel it's just a helper function to publish a message into the /cmd_vel
  topic.
- shutdownhook it's just a function that is called when the program is terminated, and stops
  the robot.
- stop_robot is the function that I use to stop the robot. It basically generates a message
  with all zeros to stop the robot, and publishes it into the /cmd_vel topic.

You can also have a look at the following video I've created explaining a little bit the
code and showing how it performs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8m0QFlX38k0

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-31**:
`rospy.Timer` was too convenient ([docs](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Timer))?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-31**:
I've actually decided to downvote this answer. If for one reason only: it's overly complicated for what the OP asks and doesn't help make the basic principle clear. We have to remember that ROS Answers primarily targets beginners (with the occasional hard question by experienced members). If ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-31**:
.. we start showing them these kind of convoluted setups for something which should realistically be something that `rospy.Timer` could do, then I believe we're not doing a very good job at helping those beginners.

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-06-01**:
@Alberto E.  thank you very much and thank you to robotigniteacademy   :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-01**:
@abdelkrim: if you feel Alberto answered your question, you may want to click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark your question as solved.